# Is there a way to fix MagicPrefs?

Tags: keychain, mouse

Sometimes if an app needs keychain access MagicPrefs blocks clicks in the allow/disallow dialog, here it is:

[image]

[image]

I can click only "Deny" from there. And now if I force close MagicPrefs and try again it's all ok and I don't get any new errors in Console.

My question is how to make it not to block keychain?

Comment: Please do not add answers directly to the question.